# Precompiled templates strange effect

Tags: angularjs

I am testing idea of dynamically changing templates. I ended with sample code that oversimplifies
whole process just to show the problem:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
    <content-item ng-repeat="item in data"></content-item>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = ["heading1", "heading2"];
});

app.directive('contentItem', function ($compile) {
    var templates = [
        '<h1>{{item}}</h1>',
        '<h4>{{item}}</h4>'];

    var compiledTemplates = [];

    for (var i = 0, ii = templates.length; i < ii; i++) {
        compiledTemplates.push($compile(templates[i]));
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var template = templates[0];
            var link = $compile(template);

            //var link = compiledTemplates[0];

            element.append(link(scope));
        }
    };
});
```

Hardcoded is number of template (0) just to simplify the code and compiledTemplates array is not used (next sample will use it)

Effect the whole list of elements is rendered:

**heading1**

**heading2**

OK. But I want to pre-compile the templates so compile process doesnt happen each time link function is called.

So, If I use compiledTemplates I just need to comment first to lines in link function and uncomment fird line (comment in code above). In the end link function looks this time :

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var link = compiledTemplates[0];

                element.append(link(scope));
            }
```

Not much of a difference (at least I cannot see the difference), but effect is :

**heading 2**

(if we have 10 items in list only last one would be rendered)

Why? What am I missing?

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/DcaVM/

Comment: I _think_ the compiled and linked object is the same in both cases, so first you append it in one place, then append it in the next place (and so it's no longer in the first).

Comment: YES! that's what I did wrong. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what I'm saying is wrong but ng-repeat is a special directive. It won't compile each item.

Read here in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) about the compiler

> **ngRepeat works by preventing the compilation process from descending
>   into the LI  element so it can make a clone of the original and
>   handle inserting and removing DOM nodes itself.**
>
> Instead the ngRepeat directive compiles LI separately. The result of
>   the LI  element compilation is a linking function which contains all
>   of the directives contained in the LI  element, ready to be attached
>   to a specific clone of the LI element.
>
> At runtime the ngRepeat watches the expression and as items are added
>   to the array it clones the LI element, creates a new scope for the
>   cloned LI element and calls the link function on the cloned LI.

I hope that will help!

Comment: It's not the case - ngRepeat calls link function for each list element, so compiling template in link function (first case) is not efficient - you can put console.log in link to see that. That's why I moved compiling of template to body of directive (i could OR should move it to directive's compile function BUT I need to understand WHY the second case is not working NOT to find solution)